# How to check primitive empty array

Tags: java

I'd like to create a method that checks every Object's value is empty.If the input object is `null` then `return true;`.If input is type of array, check it's length. Below is my method to implement this logic

```
public static boolean isEmpty(Object input) {
    if (input == null) {
        return true;
    }
        if (input instanceof Collection) {
        if (((Collection<?>) input).size() == 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    if (input instanceof String) {
        if (((String) input).trim().length() == 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    if (input instanceof Object[]) {
        if (((Object[]) input).length == 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But the problem is while I testing as like this

```
int[] a = {};
float[] b = {};
Integer[] c = {};
Float[] d = {};
System.out.println(Validator.isEmpty(a));
System.out.println(Validator.isEmpty(b));
System.out.println(Validator.isEmpty(c));
System.out.println(Validator.isEmpty(d));
```

I have no idea why `a` and `b` are `false`. Can somebody explain me ?

Comment: *"I have no idea why a and b are false."* Have you checked what you get when you do `new float[0] instanceof Object[]`?

Comment: Is there a specific reason for this method?  Have you considered using three different `isEmpty` methods which take different type arguments?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oops ! I got `Incompatible conditional operand types float[] and Object[]`

Comment: You can overload the `isEmpty` method for all primitive array types

Comment: By the way, you probably want to check if it's a `CharSequence` instead of just `String`. This will catch not only String but also StringBuilder and many other string-like objects.

Comment: @Cataclysm: Exactly. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`float[]` is not `instanceof Object[]`. If you want to check for all kinds of arrays, you probably want to get the class from the object and check its [`isArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isArray--) method. Then you can use [`Array.getLength`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#getLength-java.lang.Object-) to get its length (since, bizarrely, you can't use `Class#getField` to get the `length` field):

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

class Validator {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        int[] a = {};
        float[] b = {};
        Integer[] c = {};
        Float[] d = {};
        System.out.println(Validator.isEmpty(a));            // true
        System.out.println(Validator.isEmpty(b));            // true
        System.out.println(Validator.isEmpty(c));            // true
        System.out.println(Validator.isEmpty(d));            // true
        System.out.println(Validator.isEmpty(new float[3])); // false (just double-checking)
    }

    public static boolean isEmpty(Object input) {
        if (input == null) {
            return true;
        }
        if (input instanceof String) {
            if (((String) input).trim().length() == 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        if (input.getClass().isArray()) {
            return Array.getLength(input) == 0;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for code example. I'm still trouble about `how to change my method?` before this.

Comment: @Cataclysm: Yeah, it turned out to be more of a pain than I was expecting... I wasn't expecting `Class#getField` to refuse to give me the `length` field of an array (although it's in the documentation, as it turns out).